# Linking issue with boost mpi in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mpi, boot

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I've installed openmpi and boost. I've successfully managed to build the boost mpi libraries but when I try to run their example hello_world program I get linking errors like:

Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boost::mpi::communicator::send(int,int,class boost::mpi::packed_oarchive const &)const " (??$send@Vpacked_oarchive@mpi@boost@@@communicator@mpi@boost@@QEBAXHHAEBVpacked_oarchive@12@@Z) C:\Dropbox\mpi_tess\MPITess\hello_world.obj

I've included the build lib files into the linker path. Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks for the help,

Elad

Comment: Which lib files did you include?

Comment: libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_54.lib
libboost_graph-vc100-mt-1_54.lib
libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-1_54.lib
libmpid.lib
libmpi.lib
libmpi_cxx.lib
libmpi_cxxd.lib
libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_54.lib
libboost_mpi-vc100-mt-1_54.lib

Comment: Are you building with `Code Generation > Runtime Library` set to `Multi-threaded DLL`?

Comment: yes I chose that option